# UITableViewCell textLabel cut off

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I see some strange behavior in one of my `UITableViewCell`s. When setting the font of `textLabel` to an italic font ( `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:17]` ), a few pixels at the end get cut off. It's not looking *really* bad, but I would like to avoid it. Any suggestions?

[image]

I'm using the default `UITableViewCell` as I only need one `UILabel`, so no need to subclass. I tried calling `[cell.textLabel sizeToFit]` after setting the font, but it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of cell are you using? Can you try adding a space at the end of the string you are showing?

Comment: Adding a space does help, but creating a string for every cell seems a little bad (didn't find a better word :)). (I would set the text like this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", -original text-]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As occulus pointed out, the `UILabel` is not wide enough for the italic text. However, because I'm using the default `UITableViewCell`, I can not change this. (The `textLabel` frame seems to be set at some point unknown to me. When `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is called, it's still `CGRectZero`.)

So the only solution seems to add a space at the end of my string, as Nick Weaver suggested:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", cell.textLabel.text];
```

Comment: This fixed my issue by having a space on both ends of the text. For example an italicised "j" has it's bottom bit chopped off without the space.

Comment: Really sad that we've to resort to such ugly practices.

Comment: This bug has been around for as long as I can remember. If it's affecting you, you should file a bug report with Apple. It only affects me when I'm using a Subtitle-style cell (UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle) with a bold and italic font (e.g., "Helvetica-BoldOblique").

Answer (score 3):

It's not really the italicisation that's causing the problem; it's just that your UILabel isn't wide enough. Make sure it has enough width to accomodate the text you want.

So either resize the UILabel in interface builder to be wider (by dragging one of the right hand corner), or if you're making the UILabel in code, give it a wider frame.

Italics just happen to reveal the fact that your UILabel isn't very wide and you were just about "getting away with it" before.

Comment: Apparently, `[cell.textLabel sizeToFit]` doesn't work. How would you do it?

Comment: Hmm, others have reported problems with sizeToFit: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/98254-nstext-sizetofit-doesn.html   So either add some amount to the width, or just don't use sizeToFit -- just make the UILabel be quite wide to begin with.

Comment: Btw, you *are* calling sizeToFit *after* you've set the font, right?

Comment: I'm using the default `UITableViewCell`, so I think I can't resize the label, can I? And yes, I did call it after setting the font.